# Get favicon from a feed content

Tags: python, django

I am parsing a feed url and getting the content. I want to know, how to get the favicon for a given feed and render in django template.

I am a newbie to django and python. I have no idea how to do this.

I am using feedparser to parse feed urls.

I am using following code to get the url list from an article content. NOw, how should i get the favicon url because the favicon in some content are rendered as .png format and there are a couple of .png links. how to differentiate which one is favicon?

```
import feedparser
import lxml.html as lh
import urllib2

#Import Feed for Parsing
d = feedparser.parse("http://www.popgadget.net/atom.xml")

# Print feed name
print d['feed']['title']

# Determine number of posts and set range maximum
posts = len(d['entries'])

# Collect Post URLs
for post in d['entries']:
    link=post['link']
    print('Parsing {0}'.format(link))
    doc=lh.parse(urllib2.urlopen(link))
    imgs=doc.xpath('//img[@class="bpImage"]')
    for img in imgs:
        print(img.attrib['src'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You should go to the index page of the website, read and parse the HTML, and then look at the `link` tag with a `rel` of `"shortcut icon"`. Failing that, look at `/favicon.ico` on the server.

Comment: Can u edit the above code with the solution u are suggesting @Ignacio

Answer (score 2):

You can get the favicon from HTML document or look for /favicon.ico on the server. Here is the code:

```
import lxml.html as lh
import urllib2

link = 'http://www.popgadget.net/'
doc = lh.parse(urllib2.urlopen(link))
favicons = doc.xpath('//link[@rel="shortcut icon"]/@href')
if len(favicons) > 0:
    favicon = favicons[0]
else:
    favicon = "%sfavicon.ico" % link
try:
    urllib2.urlopen(favicon)
except urllib2.HTTPError:
    favicon = None
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Your code works fine for pages which have the favicon on their html page like www.techcrunch.com. but for sites like popgadget.net, which dont have favicon on their page, the favicon is not retrieved. I came across an app which gets the favicon for a site. [getfavicon](http://getfavicon.appspot.com/). Even for sites like popgadget.net, it returns favicon image. And in exceptional cases, returns a default favicon.

Comment: did you try this code? did you notice that it has a fallback if favicon is not found in HTML?